# Am trying to make this simple c# wb service sript work

Tags: c#, web-services

```
   [WebMethod]
    public string Meses(int Mes)
    {
        string[] Mes = { "Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez" };
        return Mes;
    }
```

Can someone help me understand, am struggling to make this array work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what your code is supposed to do. Also, you can't have two variables called `Mes`

Comment: What is expected output from this web method? Element at index `Mes` from string array?

Answer (score 0):

You might be facing a compilation error since you have two variables named Mes (one in parameter of the web method and other as a local variable). Try changing the names.